# How can I add dynamic data to the Caption in the Telerik Radgrid programmatically?

Tags: c#, telerik-grid

I am working on Telerik Radgrid. I want to add Dynamic data to the Caption of Telerik radgrid and it should be like this

Caption1: ABC(DyanamicDatafromDataset)

I have tried adding Dynamic data in the aspx page in the following way but didn't work out.

```
<MasterTableView Caption=  """< aHtml>< Table><tr><td>Caption1</td><td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Caption1_DataField")%></td></tr></ Table>< aHtml>""" />
```

Now I want to add the caption programmatically and bind data to it dynamically. I have tried this

```
Radgrid1.MasterTableView.Caption="Caption1";
```

This displays caption in the grid but how do I bind data to it dynamically from a dataset?

Comment: The Caption I tried in aspx page is as follows  <Html><Table><tr><td>Caption1</td><td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CAPTION_DATAITEM")%></td></tr></Table><Html>

Answer (score 0):

Attach a handler to the pre-render event

```
<telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="RadGrid1" 
    OnPreRender="RadGrid1_OnPreRender"> ...
```

and set the caption in the code behind

```
protected void Radgrid1_OnPreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Radgrid1.MasterTableView.Caption = GetDynamicCaption();
}
```

In regard to the *dynamic* part of the question, since the event is in the code-behind it should be fairly straightforward. I've represented the details of this as the `GetDynamicCaption` method as it depends on the type of binding approach you are using.